# How do you list categories in a category group?

Tags: categories, templating

I would like to output a list of all the categories in a category group on the front end. How do I do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can fetch your categories on the front end using [craft.categories](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.categories), which has a [group param](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.categories#group) that can be used to filter categories by a given group handle.

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('myGroupHandle') %}
```

If the category group is limited to a single level, you can loop through those using a basic [for-loop](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html):

```
<ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If the category group can be multi-level, you might be better off using the [{% nav %} tag](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/tags#nav) instead:

```
<ul>
    {% nav category in categories %}
        <li>
            {{ category.title }}

            {# Output a nested <ul> if this category has any children #}
            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul>{% children %}</ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Set up on craft is through the settings, then category button. Not through category tab.