# Showing just the child category titles of a parent

Tags: categories

I have a category group with parents each with 1 level of children.

On my category entry page I want to list JUST the children of the current category being viewed.

I'm sure it's simple but I can't figure what to put in my category template?

Many thanks in advance.

Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should actually already have a variable named "category"
pre-assigned by Craft, if you've set up your categories to have URLs in the category settings.

So this simplified code is probably all you need.

```
{% set subCategories = craft.categories.descendantOf(category) %}

{% if subCategories|length %}
    <ul>
        {% for category in subCategories %}
            <li><a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    {% exit 404 %}    
{% endif %}
```

To have different template code for your sub-category pages you're linking to, I would
put the code above in a partial _partials/mainCategory and include it with the `include` function.

```
{% if category.level == 1 %}
    {% include '_partials/mainCategory' %}
{% else %}
    {% include '_partials/subCategory' %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course after posting my question I immediately [find an answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/718/how-do-you-only-show-children-of-active-parent-using-categories)!!!

Would be good if someone can confirm this is the best way?

```
      {% set categories = craft.categories.group('areaOfPractice') %}
        {% for category in categories %}
          {% set thisIsActiveCategory = (category.slug == craft.request.segment(2)) %}
            {% if thisIsActiveCategory %}
              {% set subCategories = craft.categories.descendantOf(category) %}
              <ul>
                {% for subCat in subCategories %}
                <li><a href="{{ subCat.url }}">{{ subCat.title }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```